# Problems with ACF Repeater

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

> It's my first time working with wordpress, ACF and PHP, and well, I've
> been in this trouble for days, does anyone know what's going wrong for
> the Loop not working?

```
<div class="swiper">

    <div class="swiper-wrapper">
    <?php
                foreach (get_field('fleet_slides') as $fleet_slide) {
                $image = $fleet_slide['image_slide']['url'];    
                ?>
    <div class="img-wrapper">
               
            <!-- Slides -->
            <div class="swiper-slide">
           
                
                <img src="<?php echo $image?>" /> 

                </div>
            </div>
        <?php
            }
        ?>  
    </div>
   
    
    <!-- Additional required wrapper -->
    <div class="swiper-controls">
        <!-- If we need navigation buttons -->
        <div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>
        <div class="swiper-button-next"></div>

        <!-- If we need pagination -->
        <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>
    </div>

</div>
```

> 

Answer (score 0):

I never liked this syntax:
`while( have_rows('fleet_slides', 'option') ) : the_row();`

I just treat them as arrays. (I have a repeater called `slides` with sub fields: `image`, `html`). This code works for me.

```
foreach (get_field('slides') as $slide) {

    $image = $slide['image']['url'];
    $html = $slide['html'];
    
    ?>

    <div class="banner-carousel-item" style="position:relative; background-image:url(<?php echo $image; ?>)">
        <div style="background:rgba(0,0,0,0.25); position: absolute; top: 0; bottom: 0; left:0; right: 0; ">
        </div>
        <div class="slider-content">
            <div class="container h-100">
                <div class="row align-items-center h-100">
                    <?php echo $html ?>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <?php
}
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I can already see the images, however the swipe button does not work and the images are very small. Can you tell me if there is something wrong? I changed the main text

Comment: This is related to client side possibly. Maybe even deserves its own question.